# Is there any benefit to base64 encoding a JSON payload?

Tags: json, base64

I'm working with effectively a JSON API, that requires the JSON payload to be base64 encoded.

I can't imagine a good reason for encoding JSON as base64, it should be already safely utf8 encoded as valid JSON, so am I missing something?

Perhaps it's used as a way to serialise / compare the JSON, but I'm assuming that canonicalisation / comparison of JSON surely is a solved problem?

Comment: Binary content might be a reason? I can only guess

Comment: Base64 increases the size of the content (3 bytes are written into 4 bytes). The only reason to do so, is sending binary content in an ascii only characters format. Normally JSON contains no binary content or already has serialized it as an array of numbers or similar. So there is no real reason to serialize JSON as base64, except legacy reasons.